# Is there a way to theme/color the loading animation on a Blogger dynamic view?

Tags: blogger, blogger-themes

I have been playing around with theme customization with a blogger site. Most of my endeavors have been successful, but everytime the page loads, the large, orange "loading" graphic shows.

It doesn't appear to be themeable, and looks quite out of place given non-orange themes. Has anyone any insight on how to theme or hide this loader? I assume it is javascript based?

[image: blogger loading gears]

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit more digging and found that the orange loader image is injected with JavaScript in a JS file classic.js.

In that file the code loads HTML templates and compiles them with a templating engine:

```
blogger.templates().compile('{template:BasicCSS}\n{CoreCSS}\n{ButtonCSS}...
```

In one of the templates is the animated orange image as a CSS base 64 image.

The JavaScript code that's injected includes this:

```
.blogger-gear {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
     background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhXwBfAPcAAP/37...);
     display: inline-block;
     height: 95px;
     width: 95px;
}
```

So it's just a CSS class, and you can override it like this:

```
.blogger-gear {
     width: 128px !important;
     height: 128px !important;
     background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAKQ2lDQ1BJQ0MgcHJvZmlsZQAAeNqdU3dYk/cWPt/3ZQ9WQtjwsZdsgQAiI6wIyBBZohCSAGGEEBJAxYWIClYUFRGcSFXEgtUKSJ2I4qAouGdBiohai1VcOO4f3Ke1fXrv7e371/u855zn/M55zw+AERImkeaiagA5UoU8Otgfj09IxMm9gAIVSOAEIBDmy8JnBcUAAPADeXh+dLA//AGvbwACAHDVLiQSx+H/g7pQJlcAIJEA4CIS5wsBkFIAyC5UyBQAyBgAsFOzZAoAlAAAbHl8QiIAqg0A7PRJPgUA2KmT3BcA2KIcqQgAjQEAmShHJAJAuwBgVYFSLALAwgCgrEAiLgTArgGAWbYyRwKAvQUAdo5YkA9AYACAmUIszAAgOAIAQx4TzQMgTAOgMNK/4KlfcIW4SAEAwMuVzZdL0jMUuJXQGnfy8ODiIeLCbLFCYRcpEGYJ5CKcl5sjE0jnA0zODAAAGvnRwf44P5Dn5uTh5mbnbO/0xaL+a/BvIj4h8d/+vIwCBAAQTs/v2l/l5dYDcMcBsHW/a6lbANpWAGjf+V0z2wmgWgrQevmLeTj8QB6eoVDIPB0cCgsL7SViob0w44s+/zPhb+CLfvb8QB7+23rwAHGaQJmtwKOD/XFhbnauUo7nywRCMW735yP+x4V//Y4p0eI0sVwsFYrxWIm4UCJNx3m5UpFEIcmV4hLpfzLxH5b9CZN3DQCshk/ATrYHtctswH7uAQKLDljSdgBAfvMtjBoLkQAQZzQyefcAAJO/+Y9AKwEAzZek4wAAvOgYXKiUF0zGCAAARKCBKrBBBwzBFKzADpzBHbzAFwJhBkRADCTAPBBCBuSAHAqhGJZBGVTAOtgEtbADGqARmuEQtMExOA3n4BJcgetwFwZgGJ7CGLyGCQRByAgTYSE6iBFijtgizggXmY4EImFINJKApCDpiBRRIsXIcqQCqUJqkV1II/ItchQ5jVxA+pDbyCAyivyKvEcxlIGyUQPUAnVAuagfGorGoHPRdDQPXYCWomvRGrQePYC2oqfRS+h1dAB9io5jgNExDmaM2WFcjIdFYIlYGibHFmPlWDVWjzVjHVg3dhUbwJ5h7wgkAouAE+wIXoQQwmyCkJBHWExYQ6gl7CO0EroIVwmDhDHCJyKTqE+0JXoS+cR4YjqxkFhGrCbuIR4hniVeJw4TX5NIJA7JkuROCiElkDJJC0lrSNtILaRTpD7SEGmcTCbrkG3J3uQIsoCsIJeRt5APkE+S+8nD5LcUOsWI4kwJoiRSpJQSSjVlP+UEpZ8yQpmgqlHNqZ7UCKqIOp9aSW2gdlAvU4epEzR1miXNmxZDy6Qto9XQmmlnafdoL+l0ugndgx5Fl9CX0mvoB+nn6YP0dwwNhg2Dx0hiKBlrGXsZpxi3GS+ZTKYF05eZyFQw1zIbmWeYD5hvVVgq9ip8FZHKEpU6lVaVfpXnqlRVc1U/1XmqC1SrVQ+rXlZ9pkZVs1DjqQnUFqvVqR1Vu6k2rs5Sd1KPUM9RX6O+X/2C+mMNsoaFRqCGSKNUY7fGGY0hFsYyZfFYQtZyVgPrLGuYTWJbsvnsTHYF+xt2L3tMU0NzqmasZpFmneZxzQEOxrHg8DnZnErOIc4NznstAy0/LbHWaq1mrX6tN9p62r7aYu1y7Rbt69rvdXCdQJ0snfU6bTr3dQm6NrpRuoW623XP6j7TY+t56Qn1yvUO6d3RR/Vt9KP1F+rv1u/RHzcwNAg2kBlsMThj8MyQY+hrmGm40fCE4agRy2i6kcRoo9FJoye4Ju6HZ+M1eBc+ZqxvHGKsNN5l3Gs8YWJpMtukxKTF5L4pzZRrmma60bTTdMzMyCzcrNisyeyOOdWca55hvtm82/yNhaVFnMVKizaLx5balnzLBZZNlvesmFY+VnlW9VbXrEnWXOss623WV2xQG1ebDJs6m8u2qK2brcR2m23fFOIUjynSKfVTbtox7PzsCuya7AbtOfZh9iX2bfbPHcwcEh3WO3Q7fHJ0dcx2bHC866ThNMOpxKnD6VdnG2ehc53zNRemS5DLEpd2lxdTbaeKp26fesuV5RruutK10/Wjm7ub3K3ZbdTdzD3Ffav7TS6bG8ldwz3vQfTw91jicczjnaebp8LzkOcvXnZeWV77vR5Ps5wmntYwbcjbxFvgvct7YDo+PWX6zukDPsY+Ap96n4e+pr4i3z2+I37Wfpl+B/ye+zv6y/2P+L/hefIW8U4FYAHBAeUBvYEagbMDawMfBJkEpQc1BY0FuwYvDD4VQgwJDVkfcpNvwBfyG/ljM9xnLJrRFcoInRVaG/owzCZMHtYRjobPCN8Qfm+m+UzpzLYIiOBHbIi4H2kZmRf5fRQpKjKqLupRtFN0cXT3LNas5Fn7Z72O8Y+pjLk722q2cnZnrGpsUmxj7Ju4gLiquIF4h/hF8ZcSdBMkCe2J5MTYxD2J43MC52yaM5zkmlSWdGOu5dyiuRfm6c7Lnnc8WTVZkHw4hZgSl7I/5YMgQlAvGE/lp25NHRPyhJuFT0W+oo2iUbG3uEo8kuadVpX2ON07fUP6aIZPRnXGMwlPUit5kRmSuSPzTVZE1t6sz9lx2S05lJyUnKNSDWmWtCvXMLcot09mKyuTDeR55m3KG5OHyvfkI/lz89sVbIVM0aO0Uq5QDhZML6greFsYW3i4SL1IWtQz32b+6vkjC4IWfL2QsFC4sLPYuHhZ8eAiv0W7FiOLUxd3LjFdUrpkeGnw0n3LaMuylv1Q4lhSVfJqedzyjlKD0qWlQyuCVzSVqZTJy26u9Fq5YxVhlWRV72qX1VtWfyoXlV+scKyorviwRrjm4ldOX9V89Xlt2treSrfK7etI66Trbqz3Wb+vSr1qQdXQhvANrRvxjeUbX21K3nShemr1js20zcrNAzVhNe1bzLas2/KhNqP2ep1/XctW/a2rt77ZJtrWv913e/MOgx0VO97vlOy8tSt4V2u9RX31btLugt2PGmIbur/mft24R3dPxZ6Pe6V7B/ZF7+tqdG9s3K+/v7IJbVI2jR5IOnDlm4Bv2pvtmne1cFoqDsJB5cEn36Z8e+NQ6KHOw9zDzd+Zf7f1COtIeSvSOr91rC2jbaA9ob3v6IyjnR1eHUe+t/9+7zHjY3XHNY9XnqCdKD3x+eSCk+OnZKeenU4/PdSZ3Hn3TPyZa11RXb1nQ8+ePxd07ky3X/fJ897nj13wvHD0Ivdi2yW3S609rj1HfnD94UivW2/rZffL7Vc8rnT0Tes70e/Tf/pqwNVz1/jXLl2feb3vxuwbt24m3Ry4Jbr1+Hb27Rd3Cu5M3F16j3iv/L7a/eoH+g/qf7T+sWXAbeD4YMBgz8NZD+8OCYee/pT/04fh0kfMR9UjRiONj50fHxsNGr3yZM6T4aeypxPPyn5W/3nrc6vn3/3i+0vPWPzY8Av5i8+/rnmp83Lvq6mvOscjxx+8znk98ab8rc7bfe+477rfx70fmSj8QP5Q89H6Y8en0E/3Pud8/vwv94Tz+4A5JREAAAAGYktHRAD/AP8A/6C9p5MAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfcBRALJzWx8je8AAAAEnRFWHRDb21tZW50AEFwcGxlTWFyawokq7OcAAAgAElEQVR42uy9ebxkWVUm+q21h3Mi4k6ZWZk1MRYUJYOKzOKE/fr1D0eQppvXKtgCNqCN7fDap+3QtK2gtqCgCIqtotgoiA98vxZf2yraKJNQUIiFNRc153zvjeGcs4f1/lj7nIjMulnUkJVV5SN+v5t5b9wYTty99hq+9a1vEx6it2c+88vwkY9cPvz8zt/9LX7Pe97jb731ZnfppY89v23aZ9x+262PP3Hy+GNzTo92zl/snfP1aBSrqrp5c2PrCldVH5Asf3nLbbeeeMaXPbX7L298S+hf78f+r+/HT/3sL+Af+40eahf8H37k/8RrX/fzw88vfME3Puqqa699lGHz1JjS18bQPmM+mx2cTqeIKSDmBAhgnQVyBogAMCAZ3ntsrK9j//79n1kfTf7UOftnl1522dW/9Cu/cTURZQD4ge97Fd7wi2/BF24P8O1/vP+P8PSnf/Hw83Oe8+xnX/yw899w/vkHLt9/YCu7ioUthIx+uZpzPXHCjsRWLK5m8TVLNTbly8p4o8rrm04Onb8uF16wKU+47BHyzKc+4bPP/d+/6te+/9X/5qv69/rBH/juLyzAA3l71SteNnz/6le/7JKHPezge+qJO+wqHhacLTI7CDsStiTGs9iKhX353rH42oj1LNaTuGIMozUna5u1rG9Ued9WJQfPG8nDH36ePPGJjz72Td/wnN970xt/5oL+vX/jzW/6wmKc69sLX/iNAIDFzrb5mq/+8u/d2BzvuMpkdiRgCBlktiwwEDIkbCHsIGz770mMJ2EP9QIj9Qb12MjWgbGcd/6mrG2NxI2M1GMrGxtVPnBoTQ4eWpdD52/KU7/s8eFff+sLf6i/nu988b/E//2u3/lCDnB/3p715U/Bhz/0CQDAk7740rUQ4tNns9nPHzt28imLpgMBAgKRIUgSAICIhnaA9AcqH40EDAIRwVqCYYbzFnVdw/saO7s7mE0XAASGGSABEcFZA8MslgzVVY3HPuaSz5538OD3XHDhhR/65V/5r4v+Wn/rv74V//plr/zCTj1bt5/7udcM3z/qkouevf/AxrtGYydkIGBkMDJxifWWBAb6xRi+J0MCC/3yEFuzrO0by6ELt2TfwYkcumhLLrj4PKnHTowrIaKEjGpipJ4YqcdG1jYr2dwayaEL98uFF27JZZc+XL7iWU/+3W/8un/6za/9yR8/f/W63/Irb/zC4t3X2ytf9Z1lNwtdcsnFrxmvVUdWErtMBkJcvnoDYF38PiQMBmEg5EiqjUrWtkZy8MItufBhB4fYbz2JcRCuIKZmMRWL9RoGqpGVemRlNKlkfauWrfPW5ODBzXzhBfvk0Y88X5785CfMnviESz/8nK961uu//dv+xdNXP8MFBzbwqw8hY3jQhIBve/EL8Lu/84cAgIsvPvjew0eOPi8LkLLoRaqnh0C9u5QfqL9v5XfGGWTJIDA2921gNt1FjoBAkFMCE2nIgIAMIYv+GYwAbAwkCwQlFDgL5y2IBMQQaxjeOCJiGGMTA/N9W1s3Tsbr73j2lz/77T/z+jfe3n+mX33rL+EVr3z1Fwzgrm7//AVfj/f84R8DAH78x79v7a2/9vY/P3r0xNMBEogQEZBTie+rK80rn0AI1FvIyqfq7yECkAEmQi7WxET6MCZkERD0Z8kZRAYQgbEMgOC909QiZxATnLVgZjAJnLVirKXajeC9w/4DW1c+8hGP+t39+w+8/babbzn8tf/b14ZX/dsflNXP/Du/8at48Utf8QUDWL19xVc+86Krr7rqvx85duLJEE3jVi9STrto2eOTUMn/dPX1UcQEHp4gIObBKFLGkPRJsS5aeXUhggVhPBkhhIicMwyrqRk2cJ5BIEjKYGvEOU/eWjhjcODAfuzb3P9Xvqp+++TJk586//xDh1/6kpff/tznPa/7ggc47faUJz9p69obb3zH7s7uN+TTV1ZWdv/qfSuegFZ3/KojIP2IzIBxBIZB6OLSUJghWY0EoighMUOYIDnDGLOy650aEBEoC6wxqOoK1lrMZ3NkQXmcAZOIMZZqX6GuR7CMrq7rz4wnkyvG1eiKQ4fO//j3vfrf/e2Tn/nsWX+t3/PKl+FpT3savvPlr/r/jwE86UsfB2cs33LL7a87cvT4D4kAEAiVjVh+3vu2EhKolIF9WUhUPhnRYCjjSY31tQnuuO0ovDfIIIgI2BjknMHlxYT1foGGDBDAzHCOQTCaK8DAOYe6rmCNxWKxQNvNYYyB9x7OebRtA2YWAhFTX4YaVK4SY8zh8drk2Pn7z/vURRc/7H1vfdtvvpeI2v6j/eG734EX/Itv/8dtAG9565vwqld+Ly659OHPvvGGm/86RVnubcIpQZz4zru73+FSjMA4hiQZdrTuyOLYRRfx4Hmb2Nq3hc/dfAtCm/TlEkAQMDOECEkyjLMABDlnTQS9g7NmMBgnBqPxGHVVgZmxaBawluGrCjklEBFCiIgh9sEEIvp6BcKANRbOslhj0/r6ZLq1tf+PH/OYS9/9K2/59fcRkfSL8we//w788xd9+z/eELC+Mb52d2d+Scni6JQgT3u4/dPj/kp10OcBIAKJZvhEBMn6e0ME6xghZeSYISJwxpYETxeJnYFxDDKMGBJEBNZZ1MbAMIOthWGG9xVqP4JxBoYNBAnGWDATcsqaUwhDRNC2HVLKyDmjCx0AQkKGAWANCzPRqKrRti0uOv8Atvbte8fWvoO/uWiaK77mq59z4tXf+wMJAF728pfg+c/7FnzTN33LQ9sAnv6sL8XHPvwpPPrRF3/39dff8uZh8Wlvl09853Aw3Nd/CCKwWd4nop5gcCcEOGsQQoQIYAwhl3BBzMil3CRmVN4iQ5BSBgzBGwsmwDkH5z2c8XDOwZZqwBoLMkBOWUMGFW/BFtYaMAPEBgKgDQHMjJQSYhcgOSOniCwJoesELOSdw/pkA+uT9avG49HvXXjRRX/xXS9/xd9++bO/agoAP/GffgQ/+R9f99D2ACLCo7G/tmnCo04p6/rtLCtXSKddcT7t5/J7Jlp5ieXiEveOhZBCAhHArFiAJoBqMADA1sAZHqoCMMCkCYd3DsaYEusrWGvgrNfawahnECQQMYj1cXVdl0TUQUiNxBhGFv0QOSfkFJBSQggBXdcipSRGiIgE1jrs2795cmvfvr953Bd90dve8LNvei8A/OqvvxmvePn33Od14HO98D/zc/8RAPDoxzzseW0XLgBB7uTqT7/lPYxiDwvOWfRLBCRaqlnDIAFyyEgxDVVDEn2c9Mai2R5Sykgx66KS4gXMVBJCKu+TEUKHtm0xX8zRtA1CFxBjBBGBjUGShCwZTdsgZ9EyMiY47/Wqs37YmBJijDDWYDKZYDyZYDJZo3o0hqvG0oUkt912eOvqq679+r/54Id+7yUv/da3iwi/4uXfg59+7Wseuh5g3/6N3z55cufbRU6L+3vtfLkLQGAlISTorhaSZYVwGj5AQwghzR+sxhISXRMyDM8GUsoRbxnGGKSUYIyB834IFc44EBNSSpDMYMNwluG8QyaCtRUkZ1SVg7UVjGVYw7DWIUY1kL5QISIwMboY1RuJQCSXxDKjazuZ7p6EIaLHPPaxn37B81/wVS996Su2H3IeAABe8tLnb83m88cXAO7Oi7xqDHdj8funZ5E7LT6kL/H1Ly0EwBAygEwEZL0INgZMBMuEGBNEUJK2qAtcOowEIOWMnDJijkg5AqSMI+ssrHWQTAWdBKw1JQTlIdFsmgViLK+bAWstAEbOamzWWFhbofITQAys9di3fx895pLH0daB8+TaG67/4nf/wbs/+OZf/oUxAHzXy198r9fCPBAGsLO7/fidk7PvzFm27rSK2DvbP8Uj7FUlkCaGq4/vF52w/J9Za0pTEkTpgYSC/IkA7BhmQBD1ccaaPnmB5KwLKARiAyILYw2stTDewnmPqvKoag9r9HmWGCkECBGYdIFzTmACRAgpZhg2QAYMGYC4hB81CCJGFzp4X5G3XnZ2tg/efNON6ZprbvjAJz5xxUPLA0jCI5j5wJ0Wm04r+U5fcNkjT1jxGCJ0WiIpIFlBigTKHxAtDYGSK5TY3sd5SVoBGGvAliDIyClBsqALAV1OSASknErekdHFACFBDAExBgCMFDW+QzS5NM4hZ0FVj1D5CqPRGIYdUspw1oF7T2SMXmMJbTlntG2LEBJCSCB2ZFzFO9PZv3zB877hsvuyFvaBMIAseT8R1k7J+PfKRuS0rJ/OsPuH353WMiSUenwFVCIpoJLi/5a4ZKGaQEIEQuq6FfvXEpGZy3ZRN51zRpaMLgU4AipTAchgtggxQGQBYw2qysP7CgIBG4Zlg5wyCBpWvK9gs4M1BilGZEoIsQWzglExBhireIJkRmKgCx1C14JJHn98uv1UAP/wkPIA83lT5ZzplJ2+l/vnlV4A79EH6CuEvFIp5P5lpMTcZdInps/3CcSK6ydkpJwK/CsKBRMhiSCKoMsZnSiIIymDRF8XQrDMYAK8dxDJyBnIIcIIgyQrepgzFrNdIGcY65EloWkXSDmDVmJWCC2YtES11oApw1hNLNsuI2UgIatXy4KUkszmCyTBU37iP/+4e0h5AOfd2ipOf8qOPlPT50zGsVcIGSBiGkgDMlhCAWez5gzMonwAo3iAsQzkggIw6WIDyOV7JwTKGp+pB3gkQwDEEFeAKkKIAd45QASh6yBgtG0DwxYxBjAbBBEwEwgZGRrzU0ratZTVaFYoa71Dy0IpJTRte97V11zjAISHUgjwucTkPWO/nCEvwB5gEe39GE0AdcdLeS/qY3wp+3ougaKIhBQUImZrBn4BFSOSUiISG3ir6F9MWrKFpoVYA8MAnIUIkGKCEIZFYwYoaYeRADTNHNYrsJST4g0pCzhFRSXZlFY2wbDmASknpMxIMUJIq5EYutFiMaeHlAew1hLhDDg/7eEFcIbkb6/nl++lZP2UtXyT4gXolKpCSskmiG3SHS/qGUi0Vcx9d1AAQ4oipZSRUqMVA7NiA8xgJtR1jRAi2hDhDGCzoK4qJBGkHGCcRQwRSQQ2W8QcYNiVLmRGilCUkDKsY8BaTTjLBwuh0celBALgrNm5+IJD+SGVA6SUk+xV9+MMmf7pJSLvDWcRkcK8Aphc8gCmAgtL2c0YvAGJLigZgnG6gLai0ihKACuuwGVxiVGQuwBjdff2KBMxg40FE6Fr24INuNIZDAAIxlo461GPalTld955EDFSKi1oY1FVI2UdEaNrW0iIYAApdxAShJTUw4jAWnvtL7/x19qHlAF4YzpreBnH9yr7Tv+ZV37Odw4PWtNLAYSADNGWMJYe4XSwSXo4WBTYyTkjhTz0CZRGxposFsDIewfvKxhmtClCDCuJRARgIBKwsX8f1jfWSw8BGI1GMAUQ6roWXRcQJSGmDjF2yDnBGAaTRaaMjATJCV0XEELCvGvRdgGeKlgxoCjougXqysu+/fs/Q0T5/X/yRw9+A/iPr/n3ij4ZntPA7LwL0Ec+D0R8uovIywQMhVXSc8tIihGUppDkwh3o80JavrD2/Vnr8XKfZcb6ZILzD5wHMCGkBF9VakQ9hiCElDNSAiQRrDFYX1uHMRYAoe06dF2HLEm5iH3bGBGCVNLAjMViju3pAjEKDFtsjNcwGY0hIogxou1atE2LtckkXXjw/GeJCL7uud+MT37qYw9uJPAvP/A3AICLLj7wpJ3t2TeHLtGddv097FgQ9q4CuFgOyXIeVLuDBDasAJHIgAyCFSWk0vzJShgsGFJBCgokLCLouq7ADQreWOfUAwmBCp3MOosYE0IMIBGEtgUbo6ihsTBswKQNqKZtsVg0iCHCGou6HmE0GsH5SiuDnNA0C0xnU8xmMzCTXHTB+eb4seNf8fGPf2T00Y9+/M+qscdHPvSxB38IqOrRcRBN90z49qKBlYUbwsCKN5AzOgMZFnvgkZdQkVOhHxAPLWFmzQXYcsEOenCotG1JkFLCYrFACEFDTdauoWGzUn0IYAgxR4QYEUJE0vId49EEVTUCicLCXRexsztD23bwzmJ9bYT19QlsZTV/MAYMQgwNFrMptrdP4tixY2i7Dpc8+lE0Xyzk+Mnj/PHLL//h1/7sT/7wG9/wZrzu5/7zg8cA3vq2X8RTn/HEVQ4AHnfZo/z62vpGVXnac9ef7v4HmHdlPoBP3e1k6E75AlFvMKJJQdnPOYvmBywQS8gsyKVvkDpt2QKlNmcqpZ8yi9haxELvcq7kAlZnEKR4k547wEbLUOsNrFPACKSeI8TSOmZBXTmMxzWc06TPAFoqEiHnhNB1mO5OcfTIERw5chTWEh7zmEfCe4+268hah/liLn/6p3/6ul/8pZ//Jz/yQz/+4GgHv+EXfxo/8H0/2i88Xfb4Rz0uZ3n6YtG8COB/2nZtffTIiWUBJ3dedDK6K3PIdyr3iAhki6s+nSDC2stfxv+CCfQYANEA9HCfJVrliRtj4bxDLMwdsPYGrFP413uPEDKcq1A5A2LtBHJJBCvrYL0bwoM1Bo4NiA1yTkhZySjWWuScUTmvVQobSAYMCxITmjYitC2mu1Ps7mwjpYjNjQ1ceKEOK99y6y2w1qKqvJJOBHjUIx7x989//vO/5qXf8Yqjv/Cm/4Lv/95//8AYwHO//qvxJ3/8VwCAL33aZc+86abbX9wtun/WteHSro0gQ9jYWpOd7SmwQgLVRs1pF2i1ZSuyR6NI9vBnK61gWU3wqHD0qMT2vg9fGEM9WMSGhpp+MJSeHFRyhMqNNDEsIYMMl1DAqIxFIl1ggWBU17DMIPDgfZh5mEAybEtekXRyKSfM2waz3QbNYqFGVxns37cPG2tr6GLE0SNHIAL4ukImwJeO4dqozo973ON+7B2//a7XPSBJ4K+89fW44jOX4xMfuxKv+cnvP3jddde//bprb/oP80X7nK4NB1IqxXkGCQkRg3LKy0aNIZC9MwegT95Ocf8rhjBA6nza/QNmQEuvUSaF+9cdSj6R4jl0IdHfxQwWgKwBs4GzFmRYXXx5P1vIoEyKC2QRnSkQUcwfjBx1JI1JkUADRoKg7VrMmzl2p7vY2d3G9s4OFgvtFVTe4tChA7jg0AVgJhw+cRzz+RzOOSzahfIS2QBgWONERFiAtW9+3je9/8Mf+ujuOUUCv/vVL8V3v/IHAQBf8tRLn/v617/l96e7zfrK1JaUthsBQLcIIEfLur4wc4kLvz/LssFDK4uf74wCCq10DWX5HKGVGpAw5AJDl/A05JHKLo8xDd/3xNLeZSdJ2s1LWjV4XxV0MEEYYBIwaThw3qlXI4CdRUgR7XSKrtXhoEXoIJLV45BSxauqQlVVGI/HGFc1mqbFkSOHkUWQY4K3FilnTOqR0t0FEKPzkM45pJSeefzo0UsB3HJOPcDHPno53vRrP0X/cOVnv+uG62/5ncW8GxOthBkBnZJyEoB0hgZPXvEIxT2ToWUSuEc7mIzi5lSQPTa6u1n6Xc9DrKHSyLHeKooHXpJCipGYUq7lwuIxhjXOZylNIwNjGMaoYShayIBwAX0YzAX3XzTY3t7Gye2TmM+miIX2VfsK46rCeDRG5WtM1tYwWZugrmrEGLG7O0XbtEPpqddeqGfOFRaTUtDqUU0kJFky1ePRlf/Ht77oQx/4s7+Uc2IAj3ncI3Di2DYu/8QnX3b48PE3d130AISYiIZJ3LvA/WkP9G8lw6eBtUN3biDRMuM3Tps6xvJQ7oks4UDqH9t3+npKaFzOEwyLV2YK+lgiEC33aJmlm7IAGkIIxqmn6J+3WMwxnU4RQgdhRsoJ1WiEydoEa2sbWF9fU0CIFBVt2xYxRExnU4Q2whTuQJYEZoZhq9dobAkzFtYZ+KqGcw5CQiDCeDS+I6X0/3ziY5fn+z0EPPfrvhJ/8v4P4rLHP/qrr7/+c2/uuuSJIGCozFaWu27i7PX/CuTbLyCtmmwJA9SjfsNkL2nfPshyN3MBiVe6j2TKt7k0jHjZI+irBGR9Lw0Bd+40KioXIFYpXCkHxIXAmjhgBwBQVRVIBCkmrO/fD195tE2L2XyGEydOIMQObAyqqoJIBhuLnKGuPmaEEJCRAUdlwsmCwHC1g4Dg6xFGowoQQswCSQkppUfP53M+JznAn7z/gxARs7Fv8q4QUtUDZ1oOy53rjL16/HKGps/K/avNI7LLRE7jetnLcbnQrrI6CNo/t5SFfa6g2IFSw6gMffakT4gg5gwWKaRO/VvmIjOXc0bOmuC5BEQO2hgCkCnDOgdDjKqMjjljkGPCid0d7Nx2e2EYc8EODEzWRNhXHhJz4QtEsAGMd7AlrzBkFMUsXsgYg8o77Us0AV3bwliGc26ftZbOWRJ42RMe8Zrp7vz85TSFQrFpAGCWOPydKF1y1wu/Fz4gURsvVNA7SdqNyykNTaHQxCGxXHbs6E6vQ2XcW6c2BH5UoW3akjfSwA4mgY53YZnhM2vu4JyDdx6+8mBiWGu0X9B2OH78OKYnp2VBdf7QWELMGdZZGKNlTcq55DrKbrZskJBRmcInKOWPCOC8Q+VGcN6CDRe4uYMyiwFjDHvnzx0f4OjRE/9qlYfRs3GYdVhDVmJ1L+p0t8PC6c0hWVYMkktyaDV7tMNQ50rSJFR2LoaJX6KSH2BZGYgksGE0i7bAwrrTnNU/kSGCKSxdWIZ1TuOysUrcTBlt06JrO8znCzSLRgdRSjUBQ/o8U9DCUtpqC5vhXMEDMsBGE0lmpaozCNZpK9n6Gta6MgYnSDGibVt0XacJITOMNbfVo1rOiQF8w/O+4rF/9j8/vNEvTS/QpZ2u04Yy+tLsTHCU3IMcYYUTKCQlE1/i+jkpqCNZjUDzAb0urQJoOVZOyvZRoAcwhgu1u1ZGDqD19koLOYSEmLR5E7uItumQUlqWqYwBUGJbRtEJqOtq4B8y8eBNevjZcg1yDuQII6e0cuc9PFt47xBTr21ACG2L0AbEFBFjgrUi1jlixofW1zfiOTGAW249vF+ymNWlG1xtj64VMEabJ6c1cc7E+TsTPey0ZpEUJu8Qo3W7lrcvSaGs4ADl2nq2j3Ea46nQwpx1qGvNqokIMUW0XYdGOh0GaQNCiAhBh0f6KZ6+/0COhnby6kyCxm+jiWMhpLjKDYniqB7pzKH1MHUF6y0qo5C0Mw7eOWTpWccR3axFCB0yIpqmUdyCHNXVCJLTX7z2P70unRMD2L+1FQamZamv+/iof3MZMBxTYqZkGbh2WQRnmgq+Wx6B9mhtFfeeCzJkLJfmStZR8QEB1HBhWOArj/FoXJIsGho2i8UCqVP+f+wiVpMawinjyYpzlUxTXXlBKVVTpmARtjCS1WtVVaWtY2tR+xopRQ1nRWyCidDM58MwShZRxnKZP2i7FpW1qL0XP3ZUefveA1tbHz1n3cCXvORbrzSOF/3OVJEGKK0qydBfJ6NU3JxzmbvLBanr4yANpF3CHtgAnYEsshdFnFcIwFLiPfXDGUZFII2WUvW4wvrGOsZjXfwYImbzGU6e2Mbxwyex2G7QLYIu/hCqSm+hj+ElnHDPQ+x7EbkYChUACVIaPgbOO3jvtaEzGsM4nR6erK9jc30DIsB8oaojbK2KXpuS4IYWXejQNDp4Oh7Xsm/fJtXW3XHo4KE3vvmXfmPn27/jheeuG3jhww584Mgdx76mh/UJKN2xDOnbsmUQ8BRghqEz+is6LyRLiZbhCvNdeAe5C08gK63hHi20DNsDOdYMXTwdwlBWcGgjckil77DsGwiWpS2V0fEeg+irCaJlA8NYAoELauhgrYExFqO6wmikaB8zY1yN4SsHYgNbOQWXmMpEc0ZMXbk+jfWxCwUDFkzWxrI5mSDFSBdddNGPvuud73vtOeMDvPBF3wAAOHTowB+PJg4iS4h9AFR6aDfTsiIo/+S0aoY9Zl6g3BIuTuED0hlMl/cwjlMwBK0YcsxIXUbXaBxPMaFrOyxmC8x2F1jsLtDOW+SUVjgHUlrJK4yi0iPoa3I2egHMuujWG1irU8C+chjVNSaTNXhXY21tjKqutKtY11hb20A1rlDVNXzlEXNC03VYzHUULGdBFxKapkHbNpjPZ4hKHUblvXjj0XUdbW3t+43f/2/vfS0A/ORP/9i5oYX/we//dwDAk57wxN88fPTwz86mJ9HnYYqZCIwvo9YlNKwotmmDYCDslLIxSRnSEFCm5Y4zS3r26ZKAcle4wulcgSwgW1qzUQ0jdmkZd0jJHJJWuopYgkTLKmbZdyDWDiKRlmuGDMhZEDM8M+rRCJVxyADqUV0IoAbWK/cgxYQmdqAyFJJSQg4RkKI1FFXZbNHM4Z1T8AeQtdEIbIg2Njbfcd555303EeE7Xvpt+Ikf/alzRwj5Z1/3lfgf7/8gLn3CRe+57dbDL5juxNWZHKVce6MutQ+fgyvl1fyxIHNFio156KSh1PsoTN8iAjBk/1LGvAfEcBWBXI0lA0NkySIGK8gyqAQagbFWy9hVzWleLjoKj6BvEOlItwFbrfErX4ErDxJgXFVgo9qBfjxC7Bc4Z22GFaUqDZWEpm3KPENGDMoVRBGbcM5g7Kx452m9iElsbG39+iMf8ch/e/2NN7V/+K733eP1O2uEkC972qXPuvWW2z509MhUBRhXEcBCtLCWkY3oLpdSnw9dv57Mp7HZWIsUNOYNBsKlg2iUCWQK2smGEduCpPV5RskCZegnUGlOlGyt/J6g8rAo2IXztoBWPMR+QFk/xhoQtLZ31pXGkIWzVjN2w/C+hjEGi8UcVPSD+oqDirtjQikHDSSpq8mS0HUNMgQhhDK0itL04SJPQ6iMxbgeYTRy/3Do4Pmvf+c7/+ht92Xdzhof4MJDBz92/Nixv3een5DbrNNXRIObz0nQ5QTu1TXLX3fg+mUZkGQpZQ76CoKXrDGyGAgZXHYhymhfymnItkGEnGJBCVkHO30PyPDgo/pEECugkFgPnDYAACAASURBVLUWzirLt+/8WWthig4QscK93leACKqqQkxRWUGFSs6k4lJEjK4rtO+Ui/Ck1obGOXSxLSPmCSEomkcCkFWOQGUVAHJG84qN8QTj0eRtl1z62Ne+8fVvuQEA/t0PvApvfMO9O9bmrHiAF3/H83HdtVfj6PGTLzp27OTvnTg+H2RYl29Ew/DE4FZLH54LqVPHsc1SpJGXXtvYnigpcM4OPXtrrY5JrQybOefKiDYQQosUBYTi2ov2n2EzLH5fylljy2uqKqj3vpSxarSp1O0pZVSVCkI2iwWYGW1oVMih6P90odVyWPLQB+m6Foh58HC5ZPbGqLxZiAnWajix5e9gncNkMsLEV0ihxb5966jH6//mnb/7vredjbU7q5zAZz7rCYduu+OOd99xx4mvDm2WrPNXK+1bGiRcyBSyJgjG0xCiJSpRg03pI2QZ4i2KmrctahwiAu+8duWc8uyJdRemEHsaILpYvidBZbX2dt6XuOqWmD0xxpMxmkUzMID612vbFtY4AIoOcuEZErG6bGPQhU7JHlmTNwXFIqIIbBGH7ENOThld7LSnbwyMs2BrMXIebduVgy08mAmxnSGHgLr2eOxjH4sbP3f4vR/8Xx/5YdwHXYD7hRN4y81HZg972HmzRdN9XdukSkhKmUSDaycC2NKQnRtXqoSBN1DKLmE469QlOztk2D2jtnfLukCaVasgQzUIL3ir/PqqqrC+vo56NMJaNVIWbdnxINI2bFH66JHARbMADcOeAV0IOpQpKumWckTXBnRBewCLZoGUVD0sJqV8p5RReQcLhrVWw4i1GI/GaNsGZPR+JhWOqIvncd5CJGJnZwfT3SkgCbHrUI8qnH/Bhbj66hvD0SPHWgBXAZg/KHIAAA7Awav/4fadrYOjG1zVPaltkggrYtpn0SLqEYzTJAcssIYRO2XFsl0OYhrLQ+ImWZCQhj8Yk07r5pRhvR9KxBCCuvcyTcPMKrRASihsYoAR/V0IpY8v6g2ICdPpVGlXRIgxYro7RZaM0HXDAL5hgxDDoP7JDBAZeM8gckvNQVKqWCaBtXrNKQrmzQLsLCrn4JyHNxrnQ4g4fPQI5vMZrCH4SmO/R0Y1GaEyLONxRdvbOwzgKwF8GsCf4V5qA5wtAyAABwE8DcCzuxCeuH0c7fpmlaI0JsUskrR6HuhdQJFjKcMaBLjaDb10b61q4rQNKj9CzGlonRpjQAZw2WiP3BYypOQB77fWKtUqC2Lo4Mlj0S1KHE8ICOopsiBT0fJLS5jaWot+fFlEhrKNiQej6sWfiSxcIYD01JRBF1hKa5cIpkwn29rCGgvJGShk0C4EXfjpDM4R1icjVJVTT0IAlRBhnSVjLE6e2A7lb/4VAD4J4PYHygAMgC8C8DwAzyoX5domiLPmuo01f+l02lJMZTQzn8rlc94jdAH9lLWvVJR5/8Y+tKHDfDEHicXGuNaZ+pzgnEdVG1TWFw1/VdMwJdOyXsNC17ZFi/FUSlov+RajCjFIUKkWLpVGKmWncvAMQgpDIpiicgZUPVxJID1rOIVQEj6Vms9FAmZ4v5IUO6fj5W3TKf9/OtNSjxmbkzWsr48QYodR7UBUoW1bgBiqbWWxvTMLbdvm4nEvA3AJgMNnAMzvVwOoAHwZgH8F4CkARqso/XTabI9RXVeN7SUUMsVOBrp3z6lLMaokS5nBb5oWPB7h1iOHYUgHK5gBtO2SeVt2eZcCnLPwxoNdjaPHjmFUj4YQg6ITkEXJlk3bwDmHrusGwKeqKnRNEW4oDSJt2UYt36T0+Hv4gBUfzikjUhzYujkpdy8UI0gxYTQeYTrd0VzEVUg5oGlaxJCGqiWkBFcoX6NRjbXNCULXLkmnbFBX46IDwMKVp5tuu2Oa84B9HgTwaAAfB9CeSwPwAJ4K4CUAnlxe505T/vNpe3zMvnbOXkTQGjiXXn3OWFK+BQghYnNzA23bYt++LSxmLYQS1tfXMZ82OiHjPJJkWLJomg7RZCwyIaYpBIJFo5M0/aKllIZmTz/Ry0Y7c44cprsLzbJjBAKGvKGvAFCAmF7JM8YIoFuGmcJB6A0rhDiQSk6cOAlJgtnudgkvRW0k67ygrz02RxNYY+FrFZ5umgamEFJAhLXJBG2XUFUV1sYVtSnhuqtvOSlLmnUN4KKyGc+ZAVBx+9+6svh7lZTChq0h3mrnHax3IMuqskkC5SwSclQwRmLGzskdsDU4cfwkmkUH4wjTnbm63eJOiQi9JI7KtUlhHckpLp5AgyBzbwD9aww0raFrqY2cRBrrm1brdXZ2wCyMYXSFnBFSAATo2g4hRqBMAEH0/Yd5Re6njAi+VowhhoDJZIK68nDeaBua9TwiZyycV4HpGBPq8RpAC4TQyfHtlpjM4pabb91d2WwGwP5iAOcsBzgfwLcU92/PQM0AAEwmfl/TdOPQZgmhI+stjNPFMWAIqz4/iQIexqrqRogR1qlLzgQ4Z4fFVEAlqOBzSkgp63QNEVLWGlxhYi67uAyMsOpwpVQwg8LibdsWbFhl2KLKuWbJMEKQqF23nPQQiRAjOtNBsmCRNXHUzqVKu2TJYKNwcSY9P4BYwSC2RS1kbYT1tTEm9QjOMbz32J1OYQzDOotDBw/BGItjx0+AQGiaBjF0ZJ3NN99yx+3z2aI7rQ86Lh75nBiABfDM8lXdxeILAKlrvnh3t+zCJAiLgNAWVM8RqsponztliBE9yKGHcmEHcmcImogpI0eQkSGpVwHLQNLWrEqrKGjUkz65h4jDsjeQughjbRFlyqfMDEjW1m8s//f3h9LMokoTQut03o+YAYoDNpFzRGgTSArABULta7AhjEZjHFifwHoLQ4r/iySkGEFQ+Hk6nSHEgJAz5os5vK9EVUPisRuuu/nYHt7W3hc8554awD4ATy9u567QRNm3NT5vZ7exWGozqltMZee2CSEwnDdATuiiQHXWuLSHw8Ao6hdISMoEsSy5VqW7mHKhhEtCDLGQUgi5SLbK6pkzAsQ23SX9TE4bAmHLsN4WGbme+85gy6jrNYQQS7+gwgINurYrhmJRO4/N9QkOHDiALraYjMdYzGaIQeVefCGgChjTRYOUEiZrY0kxUugW5KxfXP7xT994BuZkCyCeKwM4D8DD7gaRRAh5K4S8egLQqZdPQOqUoLG8PwF8Kq4/nOpVGv99w0byGWhCK6zztDpouMdI2d6g+Oq0KJZNqyQITShIoZaC+w6soWsDZlNFAZ13ilQ6i5QTvPfY3NhE5RwOHtiHuq6wz60rWcQA+91+HL7jDsSoqKHtBSpJQfLFYo4U0/yKT153tWgIPP2qI4A77gsaaO9h8rcOYA1nVuwdViJKHMteU0BnEoVckYeRlb796mkew0wA7oImznvs6NPnEel0jsByaHQ5xNzLyPTvvwSwUsqDzMyFF5yPne0dLGZTcIn5qCxG4wob4zWMRyMAgrXJSCeFCDhx8gQmG+tIUdB2AVVVax8D2o8wlUVlHbWzZv4Pn/3ctbPZPJyBMz0FcB2AxbnyAHR3G0khr0wA7MX6Jew9JrbXDs3AGc8VwF0/t+fuSX/ObF6ZYFnl8pXFzoXty6Ubp9XDUjKWSI+dMcagawIOHz6Kxzz8Qjzs4i/B1Vdfr0lfTvCVw9a+A5jPZnDWogkBO9M52tIAmh4+jqZbwDkP27ejkeB9Ld45ijEtrr3mputn03l7Bn+VAFwD4O8AdOfCAATA7oq7uSsPgFjmwmg1Xx34gnsYwV6SsJ/P3E55/nI3U1H8BtGpJNUsOvBZlMJlRSSCS+JIEFjvkGMuL6lVBa0ohhhngTIbuGjmmLWCq667Hts723jGU74Y00UDADhxcgeT8RjbuzvYni6wsbkJV9fI5eAqbxxcGfdW7oSemchs5h/98KeuWswX8S7osMcA/DmA63Hm0xXPejfQAvhSAI/4PHmAeGf2iUiVsXKy515j4Lw3VbWf6tlzl68qgPR6AI7KyR8YhjmNYRirTOB6VCGV8+N6faBhtHxQsFiZFGaCMKt0fCkZ+7FxfV0tM2MULLoFpvMGQoxjJ3cQum6ofI4eP4IkGb72MLbS/kWZ7yMpFQ2zsLWoxjUZss1H//rjn20WTTpD0KTi8v8cwHsB3KdjY+5pCNgGcGPB/c1deQERdMYzcrdU6Rq2LJ8a+2llh/cav8Zb5DacwiEAcIZY3XPwVxinRp/nvE7ftE274sYLHYVWjUHxgv58ATZqALlM/nDWawKUkKK5QMJkMsHG+gTr6xvKEcgBo9FIlchyhLUOrq50SkQycrH4GEIpBSHWOvi6IggWH//oFVc3TZtwZjXkCOATAN5XEkCcSwNoCglhp8CQZwwBbZeCqxjWEmJYkXnrdxqWyV6v1Uf9NC/3UzhF57esFDPrwEm/jXnlebI8CIKICqW/PyaOBr2f1NfzrNxCKmofihAWChpoEHB0RjuAykrOw1j2aOQxHo+xsbGByleQ3CHlDO9rLNoGKUV4P0I9WVfPA8A7C/1YqipaxtbIe4vQhOmVn776xtnurLuLGiWW7t87zwYZ5N4YQAZwZUk+DuKutD0z2pyllE3lONckSgZZIYzq6EQZj+7FoHK/K/NSs9eVxS+v1e/8fiBUx7hXYpszAzRrrB1YOMbZcrxrcUZWF7anrJHwACmT4TI6ZgcNnvFohKquceDAAVXwjBEhdkjNHEkSklEEczQagW2Fpun0UGkmSAgqJAUBLCG0IuwMtW2YfvoTn73uNJTv9J3fArgcwH8r/8cHwgBQ3M7HSy6wdqYEhAitKTu3l2MxhoZFF8lKCin8fxp2+/KABDJcTugApMhtKidAwR0iQJK2kdu2W1LLRXSnF1WunLSTqDMBvR5woZlHGlTGB09S1L91hhAYj2qsT0ao6wlGkwnWRhMQAV1ogNgito0aW0yovDKQ+mmh/uzCFLrCGxCElCSETK5ysOynH/nrj18VQ8xniPcJwFEAfwPgjwB89r4QQM6GAXQAPgXgVgCPO0NFQCJo2RFylOFY2NyDgmVuTrIMna9ez49oWZ4PU7dlwbSwFMRQXHJ54XahBNCeerb0IGUyl3We3zid/bOedSpppRpQYWgBsyjJwzuAgcmoxubmJtYnE1ROFbxSbDGfz9E0LVLuhk7eqB6hsr5UFg5t2yonIGoY8pVH0zYCEvLeymIRjn/0Y5dfL3LGmicU1s8fFwM4jLN8u7ft4OsAfLRUA9WeoUDQMRMyC5HTAxhyEs2FACCXBk3OYGEdHhEdKO2BF+OMzv53GRBl5PTxv58y6lPR/mAlNgBsOUCyp2ATIZRzevWYeQNjUc4L1jatqywkCypfwXuLuqpQeYfxxgSGDcbVCATBfL6tWH0bEWMHENB1nQ56OmUiiWhrOhFgjAPrmyHEADYgy1W+/dajt1115fW3fZ4idwHgTwG8/962e+8vA5gC+F+FBnbZGS4+QxAIcP2YuHUWxgEpCEAZpmTy7HQ3s5Aqx5Wdm0PGaL1CI5oXSdJeABdFkJ5cYpwpTB7SE0BQsvjS/Ok7icbY0tPHyqmiejy8dx6VcRhPxhhVFt5VmKytwTqHnBNEMppmjpSj5hCsn0Ep5Eovd4X02YVGMQVnkErvg41IypF8VcWrrrzxhttuvmP7bjKzF2cr3p9NA8glC/0LABcA2NyrJJQsM8vYSrFMAVsMiRywnByOQQZKVs/W6TPytulQ1V4HOVOAGzlN7HrhpiiDiz2ld1BqeZKlrh8bA8pFM8AYGG9AxmBc19i3PsGoHsMywzuLqq508kgyFk2D2WKGLBlxlWxijB44VShjQTJS15U63yDBIqYEYiM6IuLaj33o01fNduft3Vz80j6790DP/UkJmwL4KwBfAuAZp7GCAIBSJztmbLZyzkKGKUWN3dYxQswwpTRrEYcj1IgEkgDqZwWyEi+stajHHqlLcKS6QErH6kWbyjm8RdQ5hQzrTQF3MFDKASVceO8xGo01tnsHpAjnHTYmG7BW6Wqh6zBfLNCFAAKGub6+FAR0SkltzCAGQe0ZKQHeOXSLKJBEFTMhm52//qu/vUpE7s7CYyUHmD9YDUAA3ADgfwJ4VKEmndIkikF2vcKwRLnQqySDYRShKxmeZT2xiy3BW4sQUuHzSWHparBInRqNNUZJkrkMihgDkaLkCUFVeQQTlVVgGHVdwRqL0XiMGONwGENV6eRPXVWoLKOuKkiIyDFiOp2ibRpECHJKCCHCeLsyRiYglIRGDAgEZy2cM4rwxSQsmZz3eTptjnz2766+5R4ufo+7zB6sBtBXBH8D4DFQZvD6alWQk4TQ5JY8VQoILUmUyChj2hlMFokSYhaMaqUQxKKhiwjkWOp1KGnEWqMADQlScbdsjFKrBKgqj6YNw8FMdVUBDFSuxmijhvUe1jCqUQU9EpjgnUHXNWgX6u5VKzAhxMJGtrbwB9MwtKn6gjwIRxAxDDl0WcQ5pvX1Ubz+uls+d9ONt54QEbmHiy8FcNvF/Xg7G5NBcygvfb1wBfxpH3RkLY+dM2VKdinkxAVx6w9JlCQIIZbp3XJEa9ADnayzA+BTV75o5iTYHrnTI7cGxNBZAyfA+niEUT3CqBqjGnmMxyN4ZzAaVUWHx8EZixQ77O7uYtEs4L1X9jAvdXmVQaSv3bURCaQzh4XEaRlwxJCchZjJGj+//BNXXnXkjmPTuxnv94r/VwD4QPECD1oD6HsEN5cw8PDVFg9bcr6iLe2u9ZNBhNo62DKXl8pUTt/QIah3IKN/XBVPzKhqr02GEMsoWR7atT1fP/e9hiRYm6ypu6/1RI71tQlGlYcvUm06lStYzKeY7cyQhOCrGqFrB0YxWImsk9EIIkDXBKSelEArwyoMVJWFNZaaRTj+kQ9/+pq2LXj2Pd/5VDbWBwroFh6sIWD1ohd7XKggYyEZCUQmJQGzQ8wRMWfkRYQxjKpyWrMLIyHC1Q5BBLPpHGtrI7DKoKBtWrgisCSSIYn1+FfDkJyRknL9DBj1qFZRRuaBui0EZAK6ZoHFbAHjnB5fkAJyzph3DfJcMKn8cEB0igneOQ0HIahYE9RrmZ5dTBDrLHnn85HD23f8/Weuu/VeuPzTaTK3FBCouT9DgD2Lr/MUnDoj0HfpAoibLHmSMum8nC0zfc4gxgwPHk7HjJKBECGk4WE+a1GPPbz3EABj62Ctw7RZIMcEZwwmkzF2d6dYn0yGE8Ad9RLvZcwbRpW35gssFgsYJlBipKwTvV3XAZLhmDXul3EwYwyEtBKJuRz3lovrVCEJqSpHa6NxuPGG22+5/tqbjt5Ll7962wXw19Dhz/xgzwFQsIAXAXji6dCwCLJzZoMJIxHFiPs2bI55Sd7MgnbewVRauvWHNkguXHvRxDGGhLXxGGtrE1hTlMhyxmg8xvraho5vMcO5CkSq/NG2HSCCWdOoBAszKqes4MVipgc5hghXVchZYJ0KNBK0HWyNxWQ8Rs6EtlVE0TknxISNjQmxmOmVn772+ttuPbx9Hxa//5uFkli/G8BtuJ9vZ2s49Inla09Cl2SZG0NbXID6HuljLBsxkvSsXO3qJcSogI11Fjkn5JBgGBAmHDlyDFXtkZMe4mRrFVTsuha+9hAQEhKYBQygGo9gjEOYz1A5D2dVkKFtFzpAmiIM22FaWOUFWctM0oMfclZDCrGAUES0vjbBfKc9+tnPXHNz1w1Hh9+XxZfS7HnPfWX6nEsDGJXF37dHY4iUjJGOW28PEmUP6Nybh8B4RowRKQRl9QiQssAQAUaTL6VbG22wOANbaFlMpGdt5oTdnV1tIhk9PcM4h/XJGJV38MZiPJ6gbTuM6gqmVCJd26BrG7RNB19VYHZ6oLOtlEaede7AO+3mTadTNPM5nDFSjy2Nx6M83Z4f+cwVV998mk7Zvd1EGcC1AH6/NNsSzsHtbJwbOAFwMc48IkY5yTwn7BaxJOn19kGiCSD0KHSQoB4ZWKtn5pEILJWTOBkAUjnrF8UVSzmYGeX8PpVR9V4rUWsdqrpGjB2IEqxlxBSxaOYIIQyjZkpMSaidQ2yKjAsAk1VixLDFbDYTIMvm5oQ2xuPu2B0nbvrMFVfdeB8Xf5UTfSOA3yvoaodzdDsbHsB/PnYQADOfhts29lUHck5FcBFo2gjnGYkzcgKsLYc3CmCtQUpStPML1h4j7CrBpDzOW6cHMVmGNxaWGHquBpdDoKKGFFIlD23TqtEx2YGxJjnBeAdKgizKJTAMGENijaH19XVIop2rrrzpliNHT+7i1CMs763bzwA+V2L+B3AfFT8eCAPIdydWScY8h7xdjcxm20Qtpaigg+ChTRxCUsxeyn2Jhl3qWLttMWZk1gxd5V1blX8VVQ1BFlhHEASkbNB2StFqmwZd6DSvSEDtdfTaVxVgDKqqLorgC6QMEKkoVOg6WlsbYzYLh6+75uZbS31/XxLo1cW/puz8v8R9JHg+UAYQ8PkHEwgAz+fxls2R32QmpJRhmNGFpIO0AlSVg7EqszZvuiLPWiRmi+BTLgOh3llY45CRYRCxubmGlHQxDevQpe58PbQphIgudCr60AUwqQqJMR4pqZIIJRS1rgCRLMYaGlUOO9uzvH2iueWaa2++/V4AO3stfL/41wH47bL4CzwAt7NhAG2pW/Pn2RWUosxjI9tV5Ta7LkpKWSmAWRAjwIiwo0rr7yLEmFlgoVPCekZvBhmlfLGI5gneoguL0qbN2NjYP7RsNeQUhY+cyhFwFiEKvFdJ11Soyar1NzDCaW1tgtm86a7/3PHrDx8+vn0WyuZVytfnoOTOB2zxz6YHuDsGAAC0mMfbfOU2jDWFGiiUWXV7wYCzDjEFmKwa/rP5AmwI41EFIcLudKqq2hB4YzAa18r+TRGj8WjlhC8p/D7FFNq2RUqqExyTtnFHa2P1REtCIAwzYgStr62hXcTtT//dtTfOZ4v2LCz+qtu/HsAfFD7FA7b4ZxMIehxO1Qs4cyqQJVrHlfdunJSNS7nM8OeouH7llVRpWAWWerw/haiKmeVYdYBw3oEDABghJjjvh969iKBtG+RE6LoOMSVYNoMkm/d6UAOIQEmrDDYCA8hoVNNiEY5/+oprbmwWbTgL1dLq4l9Vdv6fl24fHuoGIAAeCR0br+/O42OUth77TWPY9lLuznLJCYICQNYO7ODh6DarGL+KMfaKIBE7O9MyAl60/shgMV/AsENKGQw98MlVtlihwLoKIAalBLYCY1hGtcdkMqITx6e3f/KTV30upV71+D6XeT279+9LzP8rKKEG/xgMAAAuBPDlBRP4fDGQJEubRTCZ1BtZhAyTWDZkvYF3Hm1RANna2FTRpcLtXzSqFRRT0l5/Ue7ylcVoVJXE0qALLQwXsSc2IAjqqsaB8w5gNp/DeQ9LBhQTQCJV5cg7R9aYfO21t91w1VWfuw17n1JwbxO+Bsrl/y0AH76/GzwPRDNo5x7GMtPMwh1z2/l6vb6ARQiUpQuZrDHYv28Ls9kMu9MpAOUIdF3sK3tMvEPKKre2NplgPKmwe/IkrK8wmlRgGsF75Q5acmgXDWKKuOP2w5oEWuDAxMFZllmXqE2tLObznRuuO3LTdDpfnMV4j7LTP1RKvc/gfiR4PpAeYALg2QAO3QP8mto27DIT1bVbTzkTEYsAFHOCr1T2xjld7JQzQhdhLeuAiYhi+pTRtgs9i8cZWOMgmdAs5vDOYmuyhqpysFbpYjFEOEuyb71CVTmKQvHWW0/cet21d9zctl24j7v+9MU/DOD/BfCugvEnPMhu5ix6kqdC5wTuUUnUNWHGTHmyNt4gYiJnJaREqrSZh3P11tbWEMtJXltba4XMESHI2Ld//3Ai+Hy+0LP8csahA/uxVlfDFBEZwv4D+8V5Q+wsHT3Znfi7v7vhhiNHtrdX+vdnI973fMl3Qyd4b8L93NZ9oA0gA7gUwBOwnP2lu2kE0jZhGmOajcZ+0zIZb60wWUqSdJpI1BM4W6Zt2JTTMy0sO8SQsLGxocrbbLC5PsHWxiYW8zmmixl2ZzPErLAxW0Mg011z7R3XX3PV527vuhjvwfV+3vymuPjPAHg7lDB74lx09R4MBnCoeIH63vzhQhcX82lzzHnnjCXPlNkZgxRUKFEbPIL/r72z6XGbisLwYzu2r5O2qkClbFARqAsQIBas+0fY8Cf4Q9BZsKCaBWWB2CDYVN2gogoEKKoqtWjaJpOPSRw79jWLc6xmwlRDNbHHzuRIs53Yft97vu657+12u9hcxBwDP6DjB9i8IE5SXEemg9Nlxng6ptB7ywJj8PyOdV0vHQ6mzx7+1u9PxkfzNeDO6vILZHbvPnBb435Mw21TBCgU+M84riD2WkSwRWFnR4vhMs1mnucRBKbj+x1PlLllQjcMwsLazDGBIUkSrJWxskW8oCgyoCiybIkxgWNM6HR7XZzCm41H8+f9v58+fv7s8FBLSHdDwJf/Y4Aod+8ho1xLWmCbvDDibeBL4Bani0j9r1gamiAyxu9duty9GprgkuPiFdbKUfJcDgdGUYS1ljieExqDqxr/ruum8WwxGY9mo/H4aL6I02QDq/1V3u8RcBc5x/dPk11+lQToAl8An3MG6dKTiOC6juu4rtvpeJ1uz0TGBF3XJQhNEJjID6Mo7DiOly/idD6dxtPDwXgcz5PUWmvz3NoK3nd1fOuBJnv3qHiGv8l9AJBNob5+hHCT5LS2sNg8z7N8mSzSGBiukeRVpHYqAL20mYL+DaLUldBC2yQBLDLK/AIRlKzDWzk1fad18IfI8Ma3yH6+paXW2fBHGiDCETfZ8H1EDQmVZbz/HvhB37XV5lWwUm4AHyA3WmyDlau/VEbZ02TvxTa83KYJkGs5+BGiGVCnm64C+PL5Z1rXf6V1/nxLyF2JB1ggp4Xf5RQtwZa4/SHS0buNbOdmbJFVEacTZHPoEy0NnZat+lVNvkfAHWR653Gb6vvzSAJZ+XC/anb8iLn88gAAAcBJREFUxhmbQucF/kLj/b6WehO21KrK1GPgquYCQcvAnyDjWl8jkqxzttiqIkCuoeBDpEXchnhvkTbuPtLc6W9bvK+TAGjm3FMShA1f9RkvhzW/QwY5Ci6AVUmATEPB+7wUkGoi+Kv1/U+0sJ/fVAKwEj9vAlcakgyu6+7f0xLvPg0a1twWAmRIe/gKcsVp2AASlFXJAJnXK+v7JRfQ6ujXx0jb9JqGAv8EN1yXuy/U5f+ptf0dre8tF9Tq2rAZITLz15AzBH7NK74E/xCRX9lDDmeMuOBWFwEK9QIHiJLI9Yo9wbpKSbnq93XV/06NIgw7AhwnQdlSfYvjreJNEGF9Ts8iIpY/aon3sz5DsYO+fgKUgAyAvxSIHrJr6HNyy/g0UvznogrKS0Pld8qJnbtIYyfZQX5yfDwP87VHcAu5hewGcgWNd4bVnyrwD4FfkFbuwUVO8ppMgNJ6SoRPgY+B95BNpHDFMzingD5D2rh/KOgPFPh8B3HzCVA+hwHeVE/wDrKHcF3JcFnzBaOkyBA9nQNky7avf080s8920LaLAKvmItvUAaJBGKmX6GqIiDSWD5BhjQnSwVvukrvXt38BGndRdblM530AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) !important;
}
```

Comment: Great. I will give this a try.